# Fast Time Struct from Seconds

Tags: c, date, time, vector, ntp

I am looking for the fastest way to determine date components for a vector of NTP Timestamps.

The input in this case are NTP Timestamps or seconds measured since 1900-01-01, going to and from unix time is trivial by adding 2208988800 or subtracting if going the other way.  I need to break down the timestamps into the date components for other APIs that only accept dates as their components specifically year, month and day.

Using the ANSI C methods from `time.h` (`glibc`) I can easily derive the components but it's too slow for larger vectors.  A smaller vector may contain 172800 values but more realistically I'd like to be able to crunch a vector with 1314000 values as quickly as possible.

I was thinking that I could crunch the time myself and eliminate a small amount of `glibc` overhead by iteratively subtracting the timestamp input by the second divisors for each date component until I arrived at the date, essentially what `glibc` does but without timezones and some additional (small) overhead.

I'm quickly finding that it's still slow to go about it this way.

I'm working with something like this:

```
typedef struct simple_time_ {
    int year;
    int month;
    int day;
} simple_time;

size_t time_cruncher(const time_t *ntp_vector, simple_time *out, size_t len)
{
    size_t i;
    time_t corrected;
    struct tm cal;
    for(i=0;i<len;i++) {
        corrected = ntp_vector[i] - 2208988800; /* NTP Offset */
        gmtime_r(&corrected, &cal);
        simple_time[i].year = cal.tm_year + 1900;
        simple_time[i].month = cal.tm_mon + 1;
        simple_time[i].day = cal.tm_mday;
    }
    return i;
}
```

Is there an algorithm lurking about that can help me derive the computations quicker?  Something like Zeller's algorithm but going from seconds to date components?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you considered parallelizing your loop? I'm just hypothesizing, but I imagine that `gmtime_r` is already about as fast as it can be while remaining error-free.

Comment: @TaylorBrandstetter That's what I'm currently attempting as I write this.  I just want to see if anyone knows of an elegant algorithm for this. Parallelization is the next logical step from where I am sitting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that there is a great likelihood many of your consecutive timestamps are in the same month, use that to your advantage.

```
Pseudo code
1) Calculate the y,m,d for the given timestamp 't' as you have above.
2) now calculate the t0 = gmtime(y, m, 1) and t1 = gmtime(y, m+1, 1).  (Dec + 1 is OK)
3) As long as your timestamps are t0 <= t < t1, a simple add/divide is need to determine the day of the month.
4) Should 't' fall outside the range,  go to step 1.
```

One could also determine the start and end time for the current day, see if that applies to the next timestamps.

Answer (score 1):

If your timestamps is within the date range 1901 to 2099 you can take advantage of the fact that every fourth year is leap-year (this can be further extended to include dates within 1900 since it's not a leap year).

I derived this code from a date [c library I'm working on](https://github.com/chansen/c-dt) with the difference in this code I'm using the "shifted-month" approach as in [Zeller's congruence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeller%27s_congruence).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdint.h>

void
dt_to_ymd(unsigned int n, int *yp, int *mp, int *dp) {
    unsigned int z, c;
    int y, m, d;

    assert(n <= 73107); /* 2100-02-28 */

    z = n + 307;                    /* 1 + 306 (306 days between March 1 and December 31) */
    y = (4 * z) / 1461;
    c = z - (1461 * y - 1) / 4;     /* day of the year [1, 366]  */
    m = (5 * c + 456) / 153;        /* month of the year [1, 12] */
    d = c - (153 * m - 457) / 5;    /* day of the month [1, 31]  */

    if (m > 12)
        y++, m -= 12;

    if (yp) *yp = y + 1899;
    if (mp) *mp = m;
    if (dp) *dp = d;
}

const struct test {
    int year;
    int month;
    int day;
    uint64_t timestamp;
} tests[] =  {
    { 1900,  1,  1,          0 },
    { 1970,  1,  1, 2208988800 },
    { 1972,  1,  1, 2272060800 },
    { 1999, 12, 31, 3155587200 },
    { 2013,  7,  4, 3581884800 },
    { 2100,  2, 28, 6316444800 },
};

int 
main() {
    int i, ntests;

    ntests = sizeof(tests) / sizeof(*tests);
    for (i = 0; i < ntests; i++) {
        const struct test t = tests[i];

        {
            unsigned int n;
            int y, m, d;

            n = t.timestamp / 86400;
            dt_to_ymd(n, &y, &m, &d);
            if (t.year != y || t.month != m || t.day != d) {
                printf("dt_to_ymd(%u)\n", n);
                printf("  got: %.4d-%.2d-%.2d\n", y, m, d);
                printf("  exp: %.4d-%.2d-%.2d\n", t.year, t.month, t.day);
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```